# Is it possible to send mail from data flow pane in SSIS

Tags: ssis, etl, sendmail, dataflowtask

In SSIS can we Send email using Data Flow Output Column.
And If Condition is Met I want to Send Email.
I want to is it possible?
If it is possible then how can we do that?

If anyone know please let me know..
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you output to a variable?  Do a split on your data flow and have one go wherever you want and the other into a variable?  If multiple rows, put into an object type

Comment: Can you explain some about why it must be sent within a data flow?

Answer (score 1):

As @TabAlleman  mentioned, the only way is using a Script Component. You can refer the following link for sending email using a C# script:

```cs
System.Net.Mail.MailMessage message = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
message.To.Add("luckyperson@online.microsoft.com");
message.Subject = "This is the Subject line";
message.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("From@online.microsoft.com");
message.Body = "This is the message body";
System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("yoursmtphost");
smtp.Send(message);
```

**Code Reference**

- [How do I send mail using C#?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a75533eb-131b-4ff3-a3b2-b6df87c25cc8/how-do-i-send-mail-using-c?forum=netfxnetcom)

**Similar Issue**

- [Send email using Data Flow Output Column](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/eb83667f-e4a5-452b-b369-387ebedf0c1c/send-email-using-data-flow-output-column?forum=sqlintegrationservices)

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know is to use a script transformation.